# Dependencies in Helper class?

Tags: java, oop

I'm converting an old code base that uses singletons everywhere. It has a number of helper classes that make use of these singletons.

I'm trying to convert it to use DI, but I'm not sure what the best solution for this problem is. The helper class has a number of methods which look like:

```
public PropertyValue getProperty(String objId, String propId) {
    obj = dao.getObj(objId);
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    if(some other condition)
        log result
    return obj.getProperty(propId)
```

That example is a little contrived but it kind of illustrates my point. It gets the value if the object exists. I don't really want to add this method to the DAO as there are a number of DAO implementations so it would need to be implemented in quite a few places. Similar for the object it self.

I guess I could make use java 8's interface defaults, but it all just seems wrong to me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do all `dao`s have `getObj()`? Do they implement an interface that declares that method?

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without the real code.

Comment: What is "some other condition"? What is "result"?

Comment: A real code speaks more... Its really difficult to suggest something because we don't know the original structure

Comment: @biziclop yeah, the DAOs all implement an interface. There are quite a few similar methods, as well. The results are timeseries, so it allows you to access the property at a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Spring, I would recommend something like:

```
@Component
public class Helper {

  @Autowired
  private IDao dao;

  public PropertyValue getProperty(String objId, String propId) {
    obj = dao.getObj(objId);
    if(obj == null)
      return null;
    if(some other condition)
      log result
    return obj.getProperty(propId)
  } // getProperty
} // class Helper
```

and inject the helper into another class using auto-wiring again:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
  @Autowired
  private Helper helper;

  public void someMethod() {
    // ...
    PropertyValue v = helper.getProperty(objId, propertyId);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking.